# Python - Read in binary file over SSH

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

With Python, I need to read a file into a script similar to open(file,"rb"). However, the file is on a server that I can access through SSH. Any suggestions on how I can easily do this? I am trying to avoid paramiko and am using pexpect to log into the SSH server, so a method using pexpect would be ideal.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: why you don't want to use paramiko?

Comment: I am having strange connection issues with paramiko (always says "no route to host") and pexpect has worked out nicely as an alternative for the other pieces of the script which is mostly just using the run() method.

Comment: With paramiko, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the remote file system to local by using [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), then you can use is like normal file. The `fuse` module is needed by the `sshfs`.

Comment: How do you this without mounting the server? The file is a binary file I want to access on my local macbook machine.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a short file you can get output of ssh command using subprocess.Popen

ssh root@ip_address_of_the_server 'cat /path/to/your/file'

Note: Password less setup using keys should be configured in order for it to work.